# SendMessageTimeout not working properly

Tags: winapi

I have a requirement of getting length of window text. So, I am using the below code to achieve it -

```
const uint SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 0x0002;
    const int NoResponse = -1;
    const uint WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0x000E;
    static int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        int length;
        int result = SendMessageTimeout(hwnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 500, out length); 
        if (result == 0) return NoResponse; else return length;
    }

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessageTimeout", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int SendMessageTimeout(IntPtr hwnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam, uint fuFlags, uint uTimeout, out int lpdwResult);
```

I am using the SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG flag so that it comes out after the specified timeout. But, still sometimes, it call seems to be blocked at the call to SendMessageTimeout and does not come out.

I googled to see if there are any known limitations with SendMessageTimeout but could not find any.

I am not sure what I am missing here for it to work properly always.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards,
kvk938

Comment: Your `SendMessageTimeout` signature is wrong. Both *wParam* and *lParam* are pointer-sized. An `int` in C# is a 32-bit signed integer.

Comment: the `lpdwResult` parameter and return value also use pointer-sized integers, too. Here is the [correct declaration](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendmessagetimeout) for C#